# Add URL parameters to "let param = valPost"

Tags: ajax

I have a webform that sends a GET to a page using AJAX. Example: http:///forms.html?fname=Harold&lname=Smith

In the  section of forms.html (the webpage receiving the GET), I have "let param = valPost"

I understand how to use ajax to send the data to forms.html, but I want to receive the data in the URL to forms.html from a page not using ajax and process it on forms.html.

On forms.html, how can I assign fname=Harold&lname=Smith to valPost? I've read every ajax tutorial I can find but none of them explains how to grab and use the parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
<script>
  $( document).ready(function(){
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let script = 'my script';
    let function = 'function name';
    let param  = encodeURIComponent(params);
    <!-- Run my script here -->
  });
</script>​
```